# Restringir creación de archivos y carpetas afuera del www en php con apache

Tags: php, apache

Mi caso es el siguiente, con la función mkdir de PHP se pueden crear carpetas en cualquier parte del servidor, es decir si la carpeta donde se alojan proyectos que se van a publicar en la web, están en el disco C, yo con un script PHP podría crear carpetas en otras particiones (D,E,F, etc….) del servidor si las tuviera.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo hago para que la funciones PHP para crear carpetas y archivos, solo se limiten a crear esas carpetas y archivos en la partición o carpeta que yo decida?, en este caso seria la carpeta www en la partición C, y que no pueda crear archivos ni carpetas afuera de la www.

Supongo que se logra desde la configuración de apache, pero he consultado sin todavía dar con la solución, mi servidor es apache 2.4.48 con php 7.4.

Esto es con la intención de que ni los programadores y ni posibles intrusos puedan crear archivos ni carpetas afuera de la www desde el código.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cualquier usuario va a poder subir archivos PHP al servidor? ¿Qué sistema operativo y software de servidor estás usando?

Comment: Hola Triby, el sistema operativo es windows server con apache, no todos los usuarios pueden subir archivos pero si cualquiera podría tener el permiso para subirlos si el administrador se lo asigna.

Comment: En Windows crea un usuario y asegúrate de darle acceso solo a la carpeta deseada. Luego, sigue las instrucciones del [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) para que Apache se ejecute bajo ese usuario.

Comment: A que bien, no sabia que apache podía ejecutarse bajo un usuario, excelente. Muchas gracias Triby.